# Arrangements of soft bumps under a plate to minimize both rocking and bumping against counter

Tags: geometry, optimization

The goal is to pimp my dinner plates by adding soft rubber bumpers on the underside, so as to render them noise-free, i.e., clank-proof. However, I would also like to minimize resultant rocking, as happens with chairs that have uneven legs. Another thing to minimize is the amount of rubber used.

The unmodified plates have a circular contact with the surface underneath (flat surfaces can be assumed), and it is only the bumping of this circle with the surface underneath that need be factored.

(Initial idea: place the bumpers around the aforementioned circle.)

Comment: Three rubber bumpers placed as far apart as possible will provide the most stable platform on any irregular surface. That is, a tripod always has its feet in contact with the surface, whereas four legged structures often rock, three in contact and one not.

Comment: This seems more like a physics/engineering problem. My non-engineering suggestion would be to just cover the entire circular contact with an even height rubber surface.